# R code outside of for-loop working as intended but when nested in for-loop/function getting odd results

Tags: r, for-loop

Quick disclaimer-- I just picked up R a few days ago with almost no prior programming experience so I apologize if this question is silly or the code looks *awful*. (It probably is).

On to the code! So I'm using some [code from this blog](http://allthingsr.blogspot.com/2012/04/getting-historical-weather-data-in-r.html) that I repurposed to try some fun statistical modeling based on weather.

The function that I have written to pull down weather data looks like so:

```
getHistoricalWeather <- function(weatherstation, senddate) {
  base.url <- 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/{MY API IS HERE}/'
  final.url <- paste(base.url, 'history_', senddate, '/q/', weatherstation, '.json',sep='')
  conn <- url(final.url)

  raw.data <- readLines(conn, n=-1L, ok=TRUE)

  weather.data <- fromJSON(paste(raw.data, collapse=""))

  close(conn)
  return(weather.data)
}
```

After that, I'm trying to loop through 10 separate dates and pull down the weather data for each of those dates, find the average temperature based between certain hours, average humidity, and total rainfall. They dates are saved in a variable called checkdate.

```
checkdate
 [1] "20130628" "20130611" "20130612" "20130613" "20130614" "20130615" "20130616" "20130617" "20130618" "20130619"
```

And the function to filter out the specific information looks like so:

```
atwaters_cleanup <- function() {
     average_temperature <- 0
     average_hum <- 0
     total_precipi <- 0
     for (i in seq_along(gotweatherdata$history$observations)) {
         if (as.numeric(gotweatherdata$history$observations[[i]]$date$hour) >= 6 && as.numeric(gotweatherdata$history$observations[[i]]$date$hour) < 18) {                 
           average_temperature <- c(average_temperature,as.numeric(gotweatherdata$history$observations[[i]]$tempi))
           average_hum <- c(average_temperature,as.numeric(gotweatherdata$history$observations[[i]]$hum))
           if (as.numeric(gotweatherdata$history$observations[[i]]$precipi) > 0) {total_precipi <- c(total_precipi,as.numeric(gotweatherdata$history$observations[[i]]$precipi))}
         }
    }
    average_temperature <- sum(average_temperature) / length(average_temperature)
    average_hum <- sum(average_hum) / length(average_hum)
    total_precipi <- sum(total_precipi)
    return(c(average_temperature, average_hum, total_precipi))
}
```

And finally the for-loop in question looks like so:

```
pull_day <- function() {
          atwaters_historical_data <- data.frame()
     for (i in 1:length(checkdate)) {
          gotweatherdata <- getHistoricalWeather("KBWI",checkdate[i])
          atwaters_historical_data <- rbind(atwaters_historical_data, atwaters_cleanup()) 
     }
     return(atwaters_historical_data)
}
```

The problem I'm running into however is that the for-loop only seems to return 10 instances of the same day:

```
   X70.9642857142857 X69.8333333333333 X0
1           70.96429          69.83333  0
2           70.96429          69.83333  0
3           70.96429          69.83333  0
4           70.96429          69.83333  0
5           70.96429          69.83333  0
6           70.96429          69.83333  0
7           70.96429          69.83333  0
8           70.96429          69.83333  0
9           70.96429          69.83333  0
10          70.96429          69.83333  0
```

But if I manually try the same commands outside of the for-loop it seems to be working properly. In the example I'm just changing checkdate[1] to checkdate[2]

```
> gotweatherdata <- getHistoricalWeather("KBWI",checkdate[1])
> atwaters_historical_data <- rbind(atwaters_historical_data,atwaters_cleanup())
> atwaters_historical_data

  X74.2153846153846 X74.5571428571428 X0.02
1          74.21538          74.55714  0.02

> gotweatherdata <- getHistoricalWeather("KBWI",checkdate[2])
> atwaters_historical_data <- rbind(atwaters_historical_data,atwaters_cleanup())
> atwaters_historical_data

  X74.2153846153846 X74.5571428571428 X0.02
1          74.21538          74.55714  0.02
2          70.96429          69.83333  0.00
```

I've tried testing the for-loop and I'm fairly certain it's plugging the correct numbers into checkdate[x] (1 to 10) but I keep getting the same repeated results. Sorry this looks a mess and thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Looks like you need to input gotweatherdata into your atwaters_cleanup function. That is, your function may work on it's own, but it doesn't get the new gotweatherdata each time.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  If you've solved the problem, you're encouraged to submit it as an answer to your own question then mark it as solved so others searching for similar issues can find it